# NextCloud and Guacamole behind the same reverse proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx, guacamole

I have 3 servers running on 3 separate VMs.  One handles domain requests and reverse proxies the other two and adds SSL encryption.  The first service runs NextCloud (PHP-FPM 7, Nginx, MariaDB) the second runs Guacamole (Jetty, Guacd, MySQL).  Both services run independently without issue.  Each service is able to be reverse proxied without issue.  I have followed the instructions from both providers to configure the reverse proxies as required.

When I try to serve both services from the same nginx reverse proxy (so that guac.domain.com and cloud.domain.com are properly routed) the Guacamole service continues to be accessable but the NextCloud stops responding and returns only 502 errors.  If I close the Guacamole browser window for several minutes the cloud will become accessible again.  There's nothing in any of the log files that I can see which points to the problem (other than the gateway timing out)

The reverse proxy is configured as follows:

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    access_log logs/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginxerror.log warn;
    sendfile off;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    gzip off;
    server_tokens off;

#default for non-configured domains and IP address
    server {
        return 404;
    }


    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-sites/*.conf;

}
```

/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-sites/*.conf includes two configs:

NextCloud proxy:

```
server {
    server_name cloud.domain.com;
    listen 80; 
#redirect visitors to the HTTPS version of the site
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name cloud.domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #### unimportant SSL config

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/cloud.access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://172.16.1.108;
        #proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }
}
```

Guacamole proxy:

```
server {
    server_name guac.domain.com;
    listen 80;
#redirect visitors to the HTTPS version of the site
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name guac.domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    #### unimportant SSL config

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/guac.access.log;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Guac Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx-sites/guac.pas;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_cookie_path       /guacamole/ /;
        proxy_pass http://172.16.1.110:8080/guacamole/;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the proxy_pass directive for the cloud.domain.com configuration to a different internal site which is much simpler than NextCloud and the proxy continutes to work.  I suspect the problem lies with the websocket the proxy is trying to maintain but I'm at a loss how to debug it.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried following the advice of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453388/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-504-gateway-timeout with no fix